# Store curl in cache and not request data until time passes PHP

Tags: php, curl, caching

I am using an API that can only take in 1 request each 30 seconds, so what I want to do is to request the api data and store it in cache. the following visits in those next 30 seconds should take the data from cache and once the 30 seconds have passed they may grab the data again from the API, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is an example of the result from the curl action? What have you tried so far? Where do you think you would like to store the data? Have you looked up any other articles about making a cache, and using?

Comment: You could store the request response in a file or database. Within the next 30 seconds you read the stored data, instead of request the data from API again. But it may depend on what the curl response may look like. What have you tried to achieve your intention?

Comment: So, I receive json data that I parse, I have looked at apc cache and storing it in a file but there must be a cleaner and faster way to do this